# Problems with Files in Visual Studio 2022, C language

Tags: c, file, file-io

I have been in trouble with file i/o in vs 2022 for quite a while and can't find a solution, hope you'll be able to help me.

Here I'll link a sample code from a website:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    FILE* fptr;

    // use appropriate location if you are using MacOS or Linux
    fptr = fopen("program.txt", "w");

    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Enter num: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    fprintf(fptr, "%d", num);
    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}
```

the problem is that even though the mode is w (so it should create a file if no such is found) it always brings me into the error print and then the program terminates.

I can't find anything helpful online, so I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have permission to create files in the working directory? Does the file already exist and some other program has it open?

Comment: @RetiredNinja First question: I have no idea; Second question: no, the file does not exists and thus it's not used somewhere else

Comment: While debugging inside Visual Studio, the working directory is one of the properties of the Visual Studio project. You should figure this out, if only to find the file after you've created it.

Comment: What error do you get? Take a look at `errno` and `perror`

Comment: Maybe you could try an absolute path? `"C:\\somepath\\program.txt"`?

Comment: @Gerhardh I get no error, the program works fine, the pointer fptr is always NULL and goes into the { printf("ERROR"); exit(1); }

Comment: @nullforce still gets me a NULL pointer and ends the program

Comment: @MSalters how should I access it?

Comment: If opening the file fails, I would call that an error and exactly the opposite of "working fine". Check `errno` or use `perror` to see which error it was. E.g. replace `printf("Error!");` by `perror("Cannot open the output file");`

Comment: What path is the file supposed to be located in? Are there some restrictions for that path? Like "C:\Program Files" or similar.

Comment: @Gerhardh I don't know where the file is supposed to be in, since the code should create one, but doesn't.

Comment: @Gerhardh will try doing the perror, give me a sec

Comment: @Gerhardh perror works like the printf, but I have no clue on where to see the error number, it's not present in the list of errors (or should it be somewhere else?)

Comment: That does not make sense. You decide where you want to create that file and added the path accorcingly or you decided to not add a path.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `errno` and `perror`? I am not talking about compilation errors, you have a runtime problem

Comment: oh so you mean the path for the original code, so yes I do know where it is, also I've read it but haven't understood it well yet, the only thing is "no such file or directory" pops up, so that's the clue(?)

Comment: Does that mean, the problem only show up with your original program where you provided a path for your filename? Not with the code you show? That should be avoided when showing sample code. According to the error message, the path you provide does not exist. All parts except for the file name itself need to exist before you can create a file there.

Comment: nono, it happens anywhere. I am sorry I am a noob at this so Idk how to explain it better/understand it well. I only know where my .c file is, nothing else

Comment: Then show some example with path that fails. Maybe you create wrong pathnames.

Comment: Found the solution, I was using files on the desktop, not in the .c repos, Idk if it's the actual solution but it's working for now